# Вы заслужили этот знак?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, знаки

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только у меня это диссонанс вызывает? В оригинале там **earned**.

Может лучше переведём как **вы получили этот знак** или **вы заработали этот знак**?

Comment: Товарищ майор против.

Comment: @alexolut почему? =/

Comment: потому что наша служба и опасна и трудна... Вообще надо комплексно смотреть по всем строкам.

Comment: @alexolut прям каким-то раболепием попахивает - "вы заслужили знак, барин благословляет".

Comment: [отнюдь](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: @alexolut видимо, только у меня неприятные ассоциации возникают)

Comment: давайте переведем как «выстрадал»? :) или можно «нафармил» ... сразу вспоминается reputation whore.

Comment: @alexolut «нафармил» мне нравится. Или «нагриндил» (:

Comment: @Suvitruf, _награндил_ :-D

Comment: Звание "заслуженный артист" не смущает? а тут - "заслуженный значкист" :)

Comment: Вы заслужили обладать этим знаком)))